# HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException in a basic Spring boot CRUD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am starting to learn Spring Boot and I am developing a basic CRUD connected to a MySQL Database and I am testing this app with Postman. Although some functions as "getByID" or "getList" is already working I am founding some problemns with "Save" function because I got a HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException that I don't know how to resolve.

This is my main codes.

**Application:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController  
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")  
@RequestMapping(value="/api")  
public class Controller {

    @Autowired  
    private PruebaService pruebaservice;  
      
    @PostMapping("save-prueba")  
    public boolean savePrueba(@RequestBody Prueba prueba) {  
         return pruebaservice.savePrueba(prueba);  
          
    }  
      
    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class PruebaService {

    @Autowired  
    private PruebaRepository pruebadao;  

    public boolean savePrueba(Prueba prueba) {
        return pruebadao.savePrueba(prueba);  
    }

    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public class PruebaRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public boolean savePrueba(Prueba prueba) {
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            sessionFactory.openSession().save(prueba);
            status = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

**Model:**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="PRUEBA")  
public class Prueba {  
    
    @Id  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
    private int idprueba;  
    
    private String columna;
    
    //Getters and setters  
      
}
```

And finally this is the postman that I am using for the tests:
[image]

It would be very appreciated if someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Spring throwing any error? If so, at which line of which file?

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller Class should be change given as below.

```
@RestController  
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")  
@RequestMapping(value="/api")  
public class Controller {

    @Autowired  
    private PruebaService pruebaservice;  
      
    @PostMapping(value = "/save-prueba", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
    public boolean savePrueba(@RequestBody Prueba prueba) {  
         return pruebaservice.savePrueba(prueba);  
          
    }  
      
    //Other methods for the CRUD
}
```

In Postman select raw and select type JSON and test like this
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Postman. under Body, select raw and choose JSON from the drop-down menu that appears. Then write the JSON that is the request body. You **can't** use `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` with @RequestBody, they are used when the binding is @ModelAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

Like the former users claimed to use the raw JSON format in Postman is a good way to ensure the integrity of your Postman requests, you should also handle this error case in your application in a graceful manner.

Add an `ErrorController` to catch and handle Exceptions thrown at Runtime by your other controller endpoints:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorController {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ErrorController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleUnsupportedMediaTypeException (HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException exception) {
        LOGGER.error(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(String.format("Unsupported media type: %s", exception.getRootCause().getMessage()), HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
    }
}
```

This way you can make sure that other requests with a wrong formatted body do not crash your application or do something else harmful but you even tell the requestor what has gone wrong.

Comment: That was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

You read the error info, it's there saying "content type not supported". So try to use correct content type.

On server side(your rest controller), use `@RequestMapping(produces="xxx", consumes="xxx")` to configure what should be sent in the request body(`consumes`) and what will be returned as response(`produces`).

On client side(Postman/java client), add `Content-Type` header to specify request body type, and `Accept` for response type.